# Superposition of sources being less intense than a single source (deuterium and tungsten spectrums)

Tags: interference, spectroscopy

I measured the spectrum of a tungsten and deuterium sources (found in [the BDS100 source from B&W Tek](http://bwtek.com/products/bds100/)) with a [CCS200 spectrometer from ThorLabs](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=3482&pn=CCS200#8133). The CCD measures some interference when only the tungsten source is on ([see here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281112/learning-about-spectrometers-curvy-tungsten-spectrum)). I also measured the spectrum of the deuterium source. Finally I measured the spectrum of both sources. I got the following plot:

[image]
The orange line corresponds to the deuterium spectrum. The cyan line corresponds to the tungsten spectrum (the curvy line shows interference), and the black line corresponds to the spectrum of both sources. The purple line is the sum of the orange and the cyan lines, i.e. it is the expected spectrum of both sources.

Two things are worth mentioned here: the first one is that the purple line is greater than the black line. This I find to be an expected behaviour since the nearer the pixels are to the saturation point, the more non-linearity exists between incident photons and counted photons. Also the [dark current](http://www.andor.com/learning-academy/low-dark-current-deep-depletion-(ldc-dd)-technology-a-new-standard-for-low-light-nir-spectroscopy) could be producing a part of this phenomenon as well.

Now, the thing that really worries me is that from 630 nm the tungsten source (cyan) was measured to be of higher intensity than the tungsten and the deuterium source!

I don't know how to explain this result. A friend of mine told me that saturation could be a reason but I don't believe this since it is odd to think that if I provide a pixel with more photons it will count less, i.e. the slope of the curve of counted photons as a function of incident photons is negative.

I wonder if any of you could explain this result. This shouldn't be destructive interference between the sources because that would be frequency-dependent, and it is a present phenomenon for wavelengths greater than 630nm. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you would need to study your instrument more, but I would look for secular changes in the response.  For example, the instrument could be warming up with time and changing its sensitivity.  How reproducible are your results?  Know they instrument!  (We can agree that you are not looking for a physical effect from the source, this is an instrumental artifact.)

Comment: It's probably warming up quite a bit.

Comment: So you could try reversing the order in which you make the comparison, and see if that changes anything.  Other factors could be different as well so it sounds like the first order of business is check the reproducibility.