# Blackbody radiation of a tungsten lamp

Tags: thermal-radiation

[image: Blackbody spectrum of a tungsten halogen lamp]

What is the source of the humps in the blackbody radiation of a tungsten halogen lamp?

Comment: The source of the image is [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273454510_Experimenting_from_a_Distance_Optical_Spectrometry_via_the_Internet/figures?lo=1)

Comment: See this [earlier question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281112/learning-about-spectrometers-curvy-tungsten-spectrum?rq=1) that might be relevant, or might not.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have it wrong. It is a tugsten halogen lamp.  In fact, the spectrum looks just like this one.

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Measured-spectrum-of-a-tungsten-halogen-lamp_fig2_273454510

Otherwise, I think your spectrum is a combination of several factors.  Likely you detector system (a spectrometer of some type?) does not have flat response to light at different wavelengths.

Comment: Simple tungsten is not a perfect "black body" anyway, but the spectrum does not look anything like the post.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this answer. The OP clearly states that it's a tungsten halogen lamp, and the link in their comment is the same as your link.